# Retrieving multiple images from database using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php
set_time_limit(5000);
ob_start();
session_start();
include('connection_config.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>mi Adda Portal</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="sidenav.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="headings.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rancho&effect=shadow-multiple">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="w3-white w3-content" style="max-width:1600px">

<header>
<div class="w3-container w3-red w3-center">
    <a href="home.php" style="text-decoration:none;"><h2 style="text-align:left; float:center;font-family:Times New Roman;">WAP Portal</h2>
</div>
</header>

<!-- !PAGE CONTENT! -->
<body>
<div class="bgimage">
<div class="w3-main bgimage" style="margin:auto;text-align:center">

<h4 class="w3-Rancho font-effect-shadow-multiple" style="text-align:center;margin: auto; padding-top:auto;">Fashion Wallpapers</h4>
<hr style="display: block; margin:0.5em 0.5em auto auto; border-style: inset;border-width: 1px;"><br>

 <div>
<table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="20">
<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/kkf_in_fng004.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a>
</td>

<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="#">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/kk_in_fng002.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a></td>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="#">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/ss_in_fng015.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a>
</td>

<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="#">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/uk_in_fng001.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a></td>

<tr>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="#">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/uk_in_fng003.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a>
</td>

<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="#">
<img style="border: 2px solid;border-radius: 5px; border-color:black;" src="./WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/uk_in_fng005.gif" height="135" width="135">
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<br/>
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345","miadda") or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"miadda") or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$sql = "select * from miadda";
        // the result of the query
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Invalid query: "  .mysqli_error($connect_error));
        // Header for the image
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
//$image=$row ['CONTENT_PATH'];

echo '<img src="/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/'.$row['CONTENT_PATH'].'" width="100" height="100">';
}
?>
</div>

<!-- Pagination -->
  <div class="w3-center w3-padding-32">
    <div class="w3-bar">
      <a href="void:javascript" class="active w3-bar-item w3-button-disabled">1</a>
      <a href="http://localhost/miadda%20portal/fashion_wallpaper2.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">2</a>
      <a href="http://localhost/miadda%20portal/fashion_wallpaper3.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--end of pagination-->
  <style>
  .w3-bar a.active
  {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
  }
  ..w3-bar a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  }
  .bgimage {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

/* First image (Logo. Full height) */
.bgimage {
    background-image: url('bg.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
    opacity:1;
}
  </style>

</body>

  <!--Footer--> 
  <footer>
<div class="w3-red w3-center" style="margin-bottom:-15px;margin-top:15px;padding-top:8px;padding-bottom:8px;"> 
    <a href="home.php" class="footer_home" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">| Home |</a>
     </div>
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- End page content -->
</html>

<?php
ob_flush();
?>
```

Can someone please help me where am I going wrong in this part of code:

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345","miadda") or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"miadda") or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$sql = "select * from miadda";
        // the result of the query
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Invalid query: "  .mysqli_error($connect_error));
        // Header for the image
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))

{
//$image=$row ['CONTENT_PATH'];

echo '<img src="/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/'.$row['CONTENT_PATH'].'" width="100" height="100">';
}
?>
```

upon running the web portal, It doesn't show any error. But images are not displayed. Image border displays for all images, but displays like unavailable or broken image.

Here's the screenshot of how it displays:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUUgu.png)

Images are should be retrieved from image path provided in database:
"/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/" under column CONTENT_PATH

and the full path is: /WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/

attached is the screenshot of MySQL table from which I am working on fashion category:

[fashion category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJNHo.png)

Please help me out...Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you `inspect` one of the broken images in the html page what does the `src` attribute show?

Comment: <img src="/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/500x500/NA" width="100" height="100">==$0

Comment: that doesn't look right does it?

Comment: Absolutely no... but I can't understand.

Comment: try to debug the recordset - like `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) print_r($row);`

Comment: I debugged it and it is displaying everything in array.

Comment: When you debug it, what is the value of column CONTENT_PATH?

Comment: The value of CONTENT_PATH after debugging is NA.

Comment: So the problem is with the database, or which field you are accessing.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot of my table to my question above just now, please have a look. I am trying to display images from path provided in CONTENT_PATH column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content path in the database is really that: the content path. The image name is in the field content_name.

```
<?php
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection issues.';
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "12345","miadda") or die("Can not connect to database: ".mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"miadda") or die("Can not select the database: ".mysql_error());

$sql = "select * from miadda where CONTENT_PATH<>'NA'";
        // the result of the query
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Invalid query: "  .mysqli_error($connect_error));

        // Header for the image
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))    
        {
            $image=$row ['CONTENT_PATH'].$row['CONTENT_NAME'];
            //use a relative path
            if(0 === strpos($image,"/")) $image = substr($image, 1);
            $image = mb_substr($image, 0, mb_strlen($image)-2) + "/";
            echo '<img src="'.$image.'" width="100" height="100">';
        }
?>
```

Comment: It's not working... Image border displays for all (10) images, but displays like unavailable or broken image.

Comment: What is the exact value of `src` i.e. `$image`?

Comment: In inspection:
<img src="/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/ky_it_fng2_1.gif" width="100" height="100">==$0   

And in console,

Failed to load resource:uk_in_fng1_1.gif   the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
It is showing similar error in inspection console for only 5 files but there are 10 files.

Comment: Well the code works, now you have to check how the web server is set up and where the images are on the server.

Comment: One more thing I am noticing, my wampserver icon is orange but it is supposed to be green. Upon hovering, the message, "WAMPSERVER - server offline" but my web portal is running on localhost properly.

Comment: If you have a subdirectory where the script and images are, remove the leading slash from $image using `$image = substr($image, 1);`

Comment: In the wamp-->www-->miadda portal. This directory contains the scripts. The miadda directory further contains WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/ (image files)

Comment: And I added the $image = substr($image, 1);   
but still not working,and now it is displaying the path and broken image. 

Where exactly to put it? append at the end of echo or elsewhere?

Comment: I added the code to make everything work in a subdirectory, see above.

Comment: It's displaying following error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$image' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\wamp\www\miadda portal\fashion_wallpaper.php on line 91

Comment: Ow sorry, i forgot a closing bracket: `if(0 === strpos($image,"/"))` ..

Comment: Error is removed but it is same as before, broken image. 
Thank you so much for helping. Maybe error is somewhere else.

Comment: You have to make the image src match the path to the image on the webserver. Try accessing `http://localhost/miadda/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/ky_it_fng2_1.gif` and if it doesn't work then also try `http://localhost/miadda/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapers/`

Comment: When I enter both the addresses, it displays: The requested URL **/miadda/WAPContent/fashion/fashionwallpapersâ€Œâ€‹/ was not found on this server.**
and same for first one.
But when I opened, `http://localhost/miadda/WAPContent/fashion` and browsed through fashionwallpapers/ list of images appeared and I was able to open the files.

Comment: It appears there is  a bad character in the database a unicode \u200b. Let me check how to remove it

Comment: Changed code based on the guess that theres a bad character in database

Comment: No worries, it worked fine. I re-installed the server and it worked absolutely fine. Thank you so much for taking your time out to help me.